# Two procedures from one button

Tags: delphi

I was wondering if it's possible to have two functions for one button.
For example, I have stringgrid in which there are orders, and with the button I want to sum up all the orders, and with the same button I want to get back to the previous state when the orders weren´t summed up.

```
if Sender = reduceOrderBTN then
begin
J:=1;
reduceOrderBTN.Caption:= 'Show all';
qryReduceOrders.Close;
qryReduceOrders.Open;
 end;

advOrderGrid.RowCount:= qryReduceOrders.RecordCount + 1;

while NOT qryReduceOrders.Eof do
begin

advOrderGrid.Cells[0, qryReduceOrders.RecNo] := IntToStr(qryReduceOrders.RecNo);
advOrderGrid.Cells[1, qryReduceOrders.RecNo] := qryReduceOrdersProductName.AsString;
advOrderGrid.Cells[2, qryReduceOrders.RecNo] := qryReduceOrdersSpecialWish.AsString;
advOrderGrid.Cells[3, qryReduceOrders.RecNo] := qryReduceOrdersQuantity.AsString;
advOrderGrid.Cells[4, qryReduceOrders.RecNo] := qryReduceOrdersprepTime.AsString;
 advOrderGrid.Repaint;
 qryReduceOrders.next;

end;
if (Sender = reduceOrderBTN) and (J = 1) then
 formShow(nil);
//trying to get back to old state but this doesnt work
end;
```

Comment: Let's have [an action](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/What_Is_an_Action) and a flag holding the state in which the grid currently is. In that action execution event handler ask that flag and act accordingly. Then switch the flag to the other state.

Comment: That's it. You need the concept of **state**.

Comment: @Juuri You've accepted an answer suggesting that you use `Tag`. That will work, but from a software development perspective it is a terrible idea. You are free to do what you like, but I feel compelled to let you know that using `Tag` in this way is very bad practise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the Tag property of the button to track the state.

```
If reduceOrderBTN.tag = 0 then begin
  // Sum orders code here
  reduceOrderBTN.tag := 1;
end
else begin
  // Set Previous state code here
  reduceOrderBTN.tag := 0;
end;
```

Comment: Well you could, but it's hardly recommended. The name `Tag` is not informative. Use a private data member of the class and give it a sensible name.

Comment: This is a hack that may be acceptable in throwaway programs, but otherwise you are just asking for trouble.

Comment: At least you can use constant instead of numbers for more clarifying.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If anything, what would/do you use the `Tag` property for? I've worked with code that uses `Tag` for flagging of this kind. True, `Tag` is less convenient to work with in this scenario than a dedicated member (of a dedicated type), and yet I don't find the practice terribly unmanageable. (To clarify, I don't remember using the idea myself before first encountering it in someone else's code, but I admit that I'm guilty of at least not correcting it to a better method, possibly even of introducing it elsewhere a couple of times.)

Comment: I frequently use tag, usually as a sort of index that allows me to use the same routine for multiple components. An obvious answer that springs to mind is a a list of several files in a history list where, rather than dynamically adding the menu items I have (say) 10 menu items each with a different tag, that all call the same OnClick event where I use that tag to select the file from an array.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the most readable way is to create two `TNotifyEvent` procedures like this.

```
procedure TMyForm.OnClickNormal(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoNormalAction;
  MyButton.Caption := 'Reverse Action';
  MyButton.OnClick := OnClickReverse;
end;

procedure TMyForm.OnClickReverse(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoReverseAction;
  MyButton.Caption := 'Normal Action';
  MyButton.OnClick := OnClickNormal;
end;
```

You then set the default action and caption in the design editor.

Comment: I don't know if it is most readable, but certainly more correct.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: I don't think this is more or less correct. This is just an alternative that may be more suitable in some circumstances and less so in others. Even though the other answer uses a property that might not be good for flagging, that doesn't invalidate or diminish the idea it proposes.